# Header Title and Subtitles are not centering if Single-Liner

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having difficculy understanding why my header titles does not center if it's too short and doesn't occupy up to two lines.

My HTML code is like this:

```
<div class="tileBlock" id="divItinerary_432" style="background: url(&quot;http://qa.tourizz.com/public/images/_tileview/EUA0018.png&quot;) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;">
<div class="pin">
    <div class="tileHeaderBG"></div>
    <div class="tileHeader">
         <h3 class="title" data-toggle="tooltip" style="margin-top:5px;" title="All France-Nice-3 day tour">This is the header</h3>

        <p class="code" data-toggle="tooltip" style="position: absolute;top: 50px;" title="Nice">Nice</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- long Nice -->
<div class="tileBlock" id="divItinerary_432" style="background: url(&quot;http://qa.tourizz.com/public/images/_tileview/EUA0018.png&quot;) no-repeat scroll center center transparent;">
<div class="pin">
    <div class="tileHeaderBG"></div>
    <div class="tileHeader">
         <h3 class="title" data-toggle="tooltip" style="margin-top:5px;" title="All France-Nice-3 day tour">This is the header This is the header</h3>

        <p class="code" data-toggle="tooltip" style="position: absolute;top: 50px;" title="Nice">NiceNice NiceNiceNiceNice NiceNiceNiceNiceNice</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

and my CSS is

```
    .tileBlock {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 345px;
    margin: 0 auto 4px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease 0s;
    width: 260px;
}
.tileHeaderBG {
    background-color: #27506A;
    height: 100px;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: relative;
    top: 20px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    width: 100%;
}
.tileHeader {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family:'WebFont';
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #555555;
    top: -84px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
}
.tileHeader h3.title {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
}
.tileHeader p.code {
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 5px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.tileFooterBG {
    background-color: #27506A;
    height: 60px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: relative;
    top: 68px;
    width: 100%;
}
.tileFooter {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family:'WebFont';
    height: 60px;
    position: relative;
    top: 8px;
    width: 100%;
}
.tileFooter p.unit {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: 800;
    left: 5px;
    letter-spacing: 0.7px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
}
.tileFooter h3.amount {
    font-family:'Amount';
    height: 50px;
    left: 35px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 0 #555555;
    top: 8px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.tileButtonHolder {
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
}
.tileFooter p.footer-caption {
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.7px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    right: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    top: -1px;
}
```

I also used twitter bootstrap 3 for this.

Kindly check http://jsfiddle.net/ajWmT/5/, I want the title and subtitle in the first tile to be centered just like what is happening in the second tile. Both tiles have the same codes, only the length of the title and subtitle are different.

I need help in centering the header title and subtitle even if they are single-liner. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without getting into it, the width of the header isn't big enough.  If you do in your css `.title { width: 100% }` it should fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the header with the long text is centering is because it's being stretched to take upp 100% of the space.
When you use `position:absolute` on an element they will only be as wide as the content, unless otherwise specified.

What you will have to do is to add `width: 100%;` to your absolute positioned elements.

```
.tileHeader h3.title {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
.tileHeader p.code {
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: 0.5px;
    line-height: 1;
    margin: 5px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajWmT/3/)

Comment: Very nice, now I know. Thank you for providing the answer with explanation :)